# Finding the intersection of two vectors of strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have two vectors of strings and want to find the strings which are present in both, filling a third vector with the common elements. EDIT: I've added the complete code listing with the respective output so that things are clear.

```
  std::cout << "size " << m_HLTMap->size() << std::endl;

  /// Vector to store the wanted, present and found triggers
  std::vector<std::string> wantedTriggers;
  wantedTriggers.push_back("L2_xe25");
  wantedTriggers.push_back("L2_vtxbeamspot_FSTracks_L2Star_A");
  std::vector<std::string> allTriggers;

  // Push all the trigger names to a vector
  std::map<std::string, int>::iterator itr = m_HLTMap->begin();
  std::map<std::string, int>::iterator itrLast = m_HLTMap->end();
  for(;itr!=itrLast;++itr)
  {
    allTriggers.push_back((*itr).first);
  }; // End itr

  /// Sort the list of trigger names and find the intersection
  /// Build a typdef to make things clearer
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator wFirst = wantedTriggers.begin();
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator wLast = wantedTriggers.end();
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator aFirst = allTriggers.begin();
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator aLast = allTriggers.end();

  std::vector<std::string> foundTriggers;

  for(;aFirst!=aLast;++aFirst)
  {
    std::cout << "Found:" << (*aFirst) << std::endl; 
  };

  std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;

  std::sort(wFirst, wLast);
  std::sort(aFirst, aLast);
  std::set_intersection(wFirst, wLast, aFirst, aLast, back_inserter(foundTriggers));

  std::cout << "Found this many triggers: " << foundTriggers.size() << std::endl;
  for(it=foundTriggers.begin();it!=foundTriggers.end();++it)
  {
    std::cout << "Found in both" << (*it) << std::endl;
  }; // End for intersection
```

The output is then

Here is the partial output, there are over 1000 elements in the vector so I didn't include the full output:

```
Found:L2_te1400
Found:L2_te1600
Found:L2_te600
Found:L2_trk16_Central_Tau_IDCalib
Found:L2_trk16_Fwd_Tau_IDCalib
Found:L2_trk29_Central_Tau_IDCalib
Found:L2_trk29_Fwd_Tau_IDCalib
Found:L2_trk9_Central_Tau_IDCalib
Found:L2_trk9_Fwd_Tau_IDCalib
Found:L2_vtxbeamspot_FSTracks_L2Star_A
Found:L2_vtxbeamspot_FSTracks_L2Star_B
Found:L2_vtxbeamspot_activeTE_L2Star_A_peb
Found:L2_vtxbeamspot_activeTE_L2Star_B_peb
Found:L2_vtxbeamspot_allTE_L2Star_A_peb
Found:L2_vtxbeamspot_allTE_L2Star_B_peb
Found:L2_xe25
Found:L2_xe35
Found:L2_xe40
Found:L2_xe45
Found:L2_xe45T
Found:L2_xe55
Found:L2_xe55T
Found:L2_xe55_LArNoiseBurst
Found:L2_xe65
Found:L2_xe65_tight
Found:L2_xe75
Found:L2_xe90
Found:L2_xe90_tight
Found:L2_xe_NoCut_allL1
Found:L2_xs15
Found:L2_xs30
Found:L2_xs45
Found:L2_xs50
Found:L2_xs60
Found:L2_xs65
Found:L2_zerobias_NoAlg
Found:L2_zerobias_Overlay_NoAlg
Found this many triggers: 0
```

## Possible Reason

I am starting to think that the way in which I compile my code is to blame. I am currently compiling with ROOT (the physics data analysis framework) instead of doing a standalone compile. I get the feeling that it doesn't work all that well with the STL Algorithm library and that's the cause of the issue, especially given how many people seem to have the code working for them. I will try to do a stand-alone compilation and re-running.

Comment: Your `allTriggers` seems to be empty, so I would expect the intersection to be empty as well. Or are you filling it up anyhow?

Comment: If you look at the example in e.g. [this reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) for `std::set_intersection`, you see that the destination collection is created _empty_ and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) is used to insert into the destination. Have you tried that?

Comment: @AndyProwl I actually fill allTriggers from a map, since this is filled correctly I left it out of the question to improve readability.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Most of the examples I've seen pre-allocated the destination vector and then used the syntax I have. I will back_inserter now.

Comment: @JacoboBlanco: Can you show how you fill up `allTriggers`? I tried to push the first element of `wantedTriggers` into `allTriggers` and the intersection behaves properly

Comment: Could you post a complete test case? Your code [works for me](http://ideone.com/L31PGU) when I fill in the missing parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing `foundTriggers.begin()`, with `foundTriggers` empty, as the output argument will not cause the output to be pushed onto `foundTriggers`. Instead, it will increment the iterator past the end of the vector without resizing it, randomly corrupting memory.

You want to use an insert iterator:

```
std::set_intersection(wFirst, wLast, aFirst, aLast, 
    std::back_inserter(foundTriggers));
```

**UPDATE:** As pointed out in the comments, the vector is resized to be at least large enough for the result, so your code should work. Note that you should use the iterator returned from `set_intersection` to indicate the end of the intersection - your code ignores it, so you will also iterate over the empty strings left at the end of the output.

Could you post a complete test case so that we can see whether the intersection is actually empty or not?

Comment: But he did initialize `foundTriggers` to contain the proper amount of elements, so it should work

Comment: I found some examples which pre-allocated the destination vector and then just used destinatio.begin(). I will try this now.

Comment: @AndyProwl How will `set_intersection` know when to stop incrementing the output iterator? It can't so it just runs off the end of `foundTriggers` when the intersection is greater than it's size.

Comment: @AndyProwl: So he did. There's probably something wrong with the code that wasn't posted then.

Comment: @jrok: The caller just has to ensure the destination range is big enough. That's why you have to use a `back_inserter` if your destination collection is empty

Comment: @jrok: The result will be no larger than either of the inputs, so it won't go off the end of the vector in this case; the vector will end up containing the intersection padded with empty strings.

Comment: I'm compiling this under ROOT (physics data analysis framework) which could potentially be the source of the problem. Perhaps the framework doesn't interact with the STL algorithms too well.

Comment: @JacoboBlanco: No, you're just not putting anything in `allTriggers` due to incorrectly reusing a variable. See jrok's answer.

Comment: This was a faux pas on my part, while I was debugging the code I added the offending loop but never actually ran it before posting that code. I have edited my question to include the correct piece of code.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Your `allTrigers` vector **is** empty, afterall. You never reset `itr` to the beginning of the map when you're filling it.</strike>

EDIT:

Actually, you never reset `aFirst`:

```
for(;aFirst!=aLast;++aFirst)
  {
    std::cout << "Found:" << (*aFirst) << std::endl; 
  };

  // here aFirst == aLast

  std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;

  std::sort(wFirst, wLast);
  std::sort(aFirst, aLast);  // **** sorting empty range ****
  std::set_intersection(wFirst, wLast, aFirst, aLast, back_inserter(foundTrigger));
                               //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                               // ***** empty range *****
```

I hope you can now see why it is good practice to narrow down the scope of your variables.

Comment: Sorry I just added that while debugging but never ran it before posting it on here, my sincerest apologies. Vector is filled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You never use the return value of `set_intersection`. In this case you could use it to resize `foundIterators` after `set_intersection` has returned, or as the upper limit of the for loop. Otherwise your code seems to work. Can we see a full compilable program and its actual output please?

Comment: I've included the output, the problem is that I am using some ROOT libraries and a ROOT data file as my source of m_HLTNameMap so I can't provide a fully-compilable source.

Comment: I would start by fixing the problem that I mentioned, as it may be causing you some confusion. The number reported as "Found this many triggers:" will be the size that you gave foundTriggers when you constructed it. By the way, your code sample still does not compile as is - for instance, aFirst is not declared.

Comment: My mistake, aFirst is declared, and you have fixed the problem by using back_inserter. I didn't notice how much the code had changed since I last looked. jrok has the answer to the current question.